# trouble displaying system diagnostic information in C# console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to display some system diagnostic information in a console app so once I know it is displayed I can send it SMTP email.

when I call this all it displays is 
system.diagnoistics.performancecounter
system.diagnoistics.performancecounter

```
public static void GetUsageInformation()
        {
            cpu = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpu.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpu.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpu.InstanceName = "_Total";

            ram = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Mbytes");

            Console.WriteLine(cpu);
            Console.WriteLine(ram);
        }
```

Can you provide some assistance with that I'm doing incorrectly here? I'm sure it's super simple like everything else I've run into the last few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is `Console.WriteLine` is displaying the string representation of your `PerformanceCounter` objects, obtained by `Console.WriteLine()` calling `ctr.ToString()` internally, which is indeed `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`. What I believe you want is the string representation of the Properties of your `PerformanceCounter` classes.

You can either WriteLine the properties directly, ala...

```
Console.WriteLine(cpu.CategoryName);
Console.WriteLine(cpu.CounterName);
// etc...
```

Or use reflection. This will get you started...

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = ctr.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        Console.Write(property.Name + ":\t");
        Console.WriteLine(property.GetValue(ctr).ToString());
    }
```

Comment: console.writeline(cpu.CategoryName);  etc.. all of these only display the literal information I put in quotes.

Comment: This is correct behavior. What are you expecting them to display?

Comment: I was hoping the actual processor timing. maybe I'm going about this the entire wrong way.

Comment: Indeed. Check out the `Process` class.